# appConfig Unrecognized configuration section system.webServer

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, paypal

Good day.
I am having trouble with setting up app.config.

The issue starts when I try to access a PayPal node from appConfig.
I ran into the following error "Unrecognized configuration section system.webServer."

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="aspNetCore"/>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <!-- This will handle requests up to 100MB -->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="102400" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <configSections>
    <section name="paypal" type="PayPal.SDKConfigHandler, PayPal" />
  </configSections>
  <paypal>
    <settings>
      <add name="mode" value="sandbox"/>
      <add name="clientId" value="xxx"/>
      <add name="clientSecret" value="xxx"/>
    </settings>
  </paypal>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If you'e using ASP.NET Core, then why are you embedding the Paypal configuration in yoru web.config? ASP.NET Core is configured via appsettings.json file. The only config that needs to be in web.config for an ASP.NET Core site is specific to IIS. And if your question is about ASP.NET Core, please use the `asp.net-core` tag, not `asp.net` which is a different framework.

Comment: Ok, let me try moving it. Will get back to you.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the source of your current error...just something I noticed will need to be fixed.

Comment: Your Idea worked wonderfully!! Thanks alot!!